# using proxy in selenium with PhantomJS() in python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Is this even an option to use proxies in selenium with PhantomJS() in python. I saw many tutorials about firefox, but haven't seen anything with phantomJS(). Could anyone point me to better examples?